# How can I loop around an array in this situation?

Tags: loops, ansible

I have the following variables in my playbook:

```
frontends:
  - domain01.fr
  - domain02.fr
  - domain03.fr
  - domain04.fr
```

I need to be able to write the following in a file via an Ansible playbook step:

```
tcp://domain01.fr:11211,tcp://domain02.fr:11211,tcp://domain03.fr:11211,tcp://domain04.fr:11211
```

I came up with the following solution, but I'm not pleased with it.

```
- name: Setting up Apache (2/2)
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini
    regexp: '^session.save_path ='
    line: "session.save_path = 'tcp://{{ frontends | join(':11211,tcp://') }}'"
```

I can't hardwrite the domains inside the `lineinfile` method, because it depends a lot, plus there are situations where I only have 2 domains instead of 4.

Is it possible to have something like the following:

```
- name: Setting up Apache (2/2)
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini
    regexp: '^session.save_path ='
    line: "session.save_path = '{% for frontend in frontends %} tcp://{% frontend %}:11211,{% endfor %}'"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. The *line* below

```
regexp: '^session.save_path ='
line: >-
  session.save_path ={% for frontend in frontends %}
  tcp://{{ frontend }}:11211{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

gives

```
session.save_path = tcp://domain01.fr:11211, tcp://domain02.fr:11211, tcp://domain03.fr:11211, tcp://domain04.fr:11211
```